# Hidden iFrame: don't show in history [jQuery]

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, iframe, history

I've added ajax file uploads to my site quite some time ago using a hidden iFrame. I use jQuery on my site and I got everything to work really fast. There's one problem though that I haven't been able to fix: every time I make a new ajax request in my iFrame the requested page is added to my browsers history. I know quite a bit of questions have been asked on this topic, but I couldn't find a sufficient answer.

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).bind('ready', function() {
    // Add the iFrame to the DOM (iFrame is needed because of file uploads).
    $('body').append('<iframe id="post_form" name="post_form" style="display: none;" src="javascript:false"></iframe>');

    // Show forms on click.
    $('a.own, a.sale, a.spotted').bind('click', function(event) {
        // Animate and clear the boxes.
        $('.box').slideFadeOut(300);
        $('form.' + $(this).attr('class') + ':hidden').delay(300).slideFadeIn(300)[0].reset();

        return false;
    });

    // Get the form response (from iFrame because of file uploads).
    $('iframe#post_form').bind('load', function() {
        var response = $(this).contents().find('body').html()

        if (response.length) {      
            $('div#message').html(response).animate({
                opacity: 'show',
                height: 'show',
                borderWidth: '1px'
            }, 300);
        } else {
            $('.box').slideFadeOut(300);
        }
    });
});
```

In my HTML code I've set the target attribute of my form to `#post_form`. I also tried to create a new iFrame for every request or set the frame.location manually, but couldn't get that to work in combination with file uploads. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your problem with having those pages inside the history?

Comment: It breaks the browser's back button and it's strange for the user to see a page in the history he doesn't even know exists.

Comment: The problem as far as I see is that you **don't** use ajax, you submit a form the usual way, so the history will grow. You coukd use an flash-uploader, they shouldn't affect the history.

Comment: I'm aware you can use a flash uploader, but I know there are also alternatives without flash. I know I currently don't use ajax (because I make the form set the iFrame directly), but I can't figure out how to set the iFrame's contents when I use a file upload form. Obviously I can't use XMLHTTPRequest because of file uploads.